# Firebase Database get data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve data one by one from firebase android when i press a button, but the problem is that when button is clicked i get the first child and on second click i don't get the second child.

```
  public void nextQuestion(View view) {
            mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https:..../Questions");
            mRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        GetData gd = postSnapshot.getValue(GetData.class);
                        String value = gd.getQuestion();
                        String rb1 = gd.getAnswerA();
                        String rb2 = gd.getAnswerB();
                        String rb3 = gd.getAnswerC();
                        String answer = gd.getCorrectAnswer();


                        pytja.setText(value);
                        aR.setText(rb1);
                        bR.setText(rb2);
                        cR.setText(rb3);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {


                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: You've not shown the button click and these methods are empty, so please show a [mcve] of the problem, otherwise your question may be closed as unclear. [Edit] accordingly.

Comment: Basically what i want is on button clicked  retrieve first child's data and show on textbox and radiobutton, than when i click again the button get another   child's data and so on.

Comment: Okay, well, you are looping over **everything** in Firebase, so I don't think you should do that if you want to "iterate" the data when you click the button.

Comment: what i did is that i added finish(); at the end onDataChange and it worked.

Comment: Um. That will close the current activity. I don't think you want that

Comment: Yes it closes the current activity but opens same activity with second child's data when button pressed again

Comment: Try `break;` instead of `finish()`. It should do the same thing, if that is all you want